# Timeout attribute ignored

Tags: c#, .net, xunit.net

I use console runner (xUnit 2.4.1) to execute set of tests. Some tests should fail in case they need too long to finish, but it seems like `Timeout` attribute is ignored.

This is my simple test method that should fail:

```
[Fact(Timeout = 1000)]
public void ShouldTimeout()
{
    Thread.Sleep(15000);
}
```

I execute runner with the option `-parallel none` in order to avoid [undefined behaviour](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/master/src/xunit.core/FactAttribute.cs#L28):

```
xunit.console.exe tests.dll -parallel none -method "Tests.TessClass.ShouldTimeout"
```

and I also added `[assembly: CollectionBehavior(DisableTestParallelization = true)]` into my assembly configuration.

The test, however, still finishes successfully with the following output.

```
xUnit.net Console Runner v2.4.1 (64-bit Desktop .NET 4.5.2, runtime: 4.0.30319.42000)
  Discovering: tests
  Discovered:  tests
  Starting:    tests
  Finished:    tests
=== TEST EXECUTION SUMMARY ===
   tests  Total: 1, Errors: 0, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0, Time: 15,151s
```

Did I miss something? Is the parallelization still not disabled and therefore `Timeout` is ignored?

Comment: Does timeout work if you run test from Visual Studio?

Comment: @Yura, no, it does not work. I tried visual studio, and also rider and still the same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like xUnit code has some internal SynchronizationContext usage, which results in all threads blocked when synchronous wait is executed inside a test - i.e. Thread.Sleep().
[See source code](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/9d10262a3694bb099ddd783d735aba2a7aac759d/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/Frameworks/Runners/TestInvoker.cs#L232)

But, `Timeout` works just fine if your test code is fully `async`:

```
[Fact(Timeout = 1000)]
public async void ShouldTimeout()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
}
```

So I see 2 options here for you: either create a bug for xUnit regarding synchronous code blocking breaking `Timeout` behavior or rewrite your code to be `async` if your code base allows it.

Answer (score 0):

If your method is not async, you can maybe try to wrap it.

Action act = () => _class.Method();
await Task.Run(act);

Answer (score -1):

In xUnit v2, the `[Timeout]` attribute is no longer supported.

Details are here: [Migrating unit tests from v1 to v2](https://xunit.net/docs/test-migration.html)

Excerpt:

> The support for tests that automatically time out has been removed from xUnit.net v2, and there is no direct replacement for this feature. The reason it was removed was that v2 is designed from the ground up to be async and parallel, and accurately timing tests in such a design is effectively impossible.

While I'd expect a compile time error, I note that you're using a v2 runner...

Comment: Not true, they added it back in v2.4.0. - https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/217#issuecomment-408958424